# SYMFONY2 works great locally, but in server Class not found in AppKernel

Tags: svn, symfony

Im having this trouble in where my application runs great locally, but when i upload it to the server it fails with whatever valid direction i put in.
Im using SVN as a code versioner (trough Eclipse), and im working with Symphony2.

**Server**: in the server i have access to a shell for my directory, it runs PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 with Suhosin-Patch.

**Local**: PHP/5.4.10.

**The error**:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Cv\DBBundle\CvDBBundle' not found in enter code here/var/www/grupo36/public_html/symfony/app/AppKernel.php line 22
```

**AppKernel.php:**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new CV\DBBundle\CvDBBundle(), 
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

---

Can you please guys help? ive look in other posts but they doesnt fit my case.

Comment: make sure your lower and upper cases are correct in the Filesystem as well as in the Classnames and Namespaces.

Comment: stupid question, but did you follow the process for deploying a Symfony2 app including cache cleaning? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html

Comment: and: in the past I had a "problem" with composer that I installed/uninstalled many bundles during development and the vendor directory was corrupted and I did not notice it. In other words: if you remove everything in the vendor directory and run composer install or composer update, does the app run locally?